# Implicit differentiation in MV Calculus

Tags: multivariable-calculus, proof-verification

I'm trying to make sense of implicit differentiation in MV Calculus, so I'd like to get feedback on if both the statement and the solution make sense:

Let $F: \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a $C^1$ function and suppose that $F(a,b,c)=0$ for certain $(a,b,c) \in \mathbb{R}^3$. Suppose also there exists $C^1$ functions $f,g,h: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(a,b)=c$, $g(a,c)=b$ and $h(b,c)=a$. Then $$D_2f(a,b)D_1g(a,c)D_2h(b,c)=-1.$$

Proof: If $i: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ is defined with $i(x,y)=(x,y,f(x,y))$, then $$0=(F \circ i)(x,y)$$ so that by the chain rule, $$(0,0)=(F \circ i)'(x,y) =$$ \begin{pmatrix} D_1F(x,y,f(x,y)) & D_2F(x,y,f(x,y)) & D_3F(x,y,f(x,y)) \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \\ D_1f(x,y) & D_2f(x,y) \end{pmatrix} (this is suposed to be matrix multiplication), from which we obtain $$0=D_2F(x,y,f(x,y))+D_3F(x,y,f(x,y)) D_2f(x,y),$$ which means $$D_2f(x,y)=-\frac{D_2F(x,y,f(x,y))}{D_3F(x,y,f(x,y))},$$ whenever $D_3F(x,y,f(x,y)) \neq 0$. Using similar arguments we can obtain $$D_1g(x,y)=-\frac{D_1F(x,g(x,y),y)}{D_2F(x,g(x,y),y)},$$ and $$D_2h(x,y)=-\frac{D_3F(h(x,y),x,y)}{D_1F(h(x,y),x,y)},$$ whenever $D_2F(x,g(x,y),y) \neq 0$ and $D_1F(h(x,y),x,y) \neq 0$. We therefore get the desired result by plugging in the appropriate values on the three expressions and multiplying out.